# Karaf PaxExam getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid BundleContext

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf, blueprint-osgi

Hi i am loading some features and bundles in runtime using FeaturesService and  BundleContext. All these things are loaded successfully. After that if i do an operation on bundlecontext object i am getting 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid BundleContext.

```
@Inject
FeaturesService service;
@Before
public void init() throws Exception{
    service.installFeature("hibernate");
    service.installFeature("hibernate-validator");
    service.installFeature("transaction");
    service.installFeature("jpa");
    service.installFeature("hibernate-envers");
    service.installFeature("hibernate-envers");
    bc.installBundle("wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0").start();
    service.installFeature("DBHandler");
    bc.getBundle(); // Fails
}
```

After a lot of browsing i understood you need to refresh the bundles. How to do it programatically and get a refeshed bundleContext object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixed my problem

```
public  void refreshBundles() { 

        Bundle currentBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MyTest.class); 
        if (currentBundle == null) { 
            return; 
        } 

        BundleContext bundleContext = currentBundle.getBundleContext(); 
        if (bundleContext == null) { 
            return; 
        } 

        Bundle systemBundle = bundleContext.getBundle(0); 
        if (systemBundle == null) { 
            return; 
        } 

        FrameworkWiring frameworkWiring = systemBundle.adapt(FrameworkWiring.class); 
        frameworkWiring.refreshBundles(null); 
        bc = frameworkWiring.getBundle().getBundleContext();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have this exception when you are using a bundle which is not valid : it has been stopped, or refreshed (a refresh stop the bundle and start a new instance)

When you install a feature, by default, Karaf try to define a list of bundles to refresh because of the new capabilities. For example, if a bundle have an optional dependency on a package, and the new feature add this package, then this bundle will be refreshed, in order to update his wires. This is transitive : all dependent bundles are refreshed too.

Moreover, when you use the "wrap" protocol, it create a bundle from a jar by importing all used packaged with a resolution 'optional'

In your case, I suppose the feature 'DBHandler' add a package which is used by your bundle.

You can :

- After installing the features, look up your bundle by SymbolicName, with the BundleContext.getBundles() : You will have an instance of a valid bundle
- Use the option `NoAutoRefreshBundles` to disable the refresh when installing a feature (`featureService.installFeature("..", EnumSet.of(FeatureService.NoAutoRefreshBundles))`). But it's not a good idea as some bundle will not see the new package

Comment: Jermie i found a way to refresh and update the bundleContext which took care of my problem

Comment: In case anybody looked forward to using Jérémie solution, look for the enum in `FeaturesService.Option` instead of simply `FeaturesService`